# Button OnClick event not firing from inside a WebControl

Tags: c#, button, updatepanel, web-controls

I have a WebControl that contains some Textboxes and a Button. Everything displays beautifully. When the Button is clicked, I need the server to do some stuff with the contents of the Textboxes. So that the contents of the Textboxes would be preserved after postback, I put the Textboxes and Button in separate UpdatePanels and set their UpdateMode to UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional. I *do not* need to handle this event in the page; I *always* want the btnSubmit_Click event defined in the WebControl to execute when the button is clicked.

I assumed that this would be easier than raising the event for the containing Page to handle, but alas! So far, I cannot get the event to fire. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public class EditUserSettings : WebControl
{
    private TextBox txtShort_name;
    private TextBox txtServco_No;
    private TextBox txtEmp_No;
    private Button btnSubmit;
    private UpdatePanel pnlControls;
    private UpdatePanel pnlButton;

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        txtShort_name = new TextBox();
        txtServco_No = new TextBox();
        txtEmp_No = new TextBox();
        btnSubmit = new Button();

        pnlControls = new UpdatePanel();
        pnlButton = new UpdatePanel();

        pnlControls.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;
        pnlButton.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;

        btnSubmit.Text = "Submit";
        btnSubmit.CssClass = "btn btn-primary btn-large";
        btnSubmit.Click += new EventHandler(btnSubmit_Click);

        txtShort_name.Text = HttpContext.Current.Profile["Short_name"].ToString();
        txtServco_No.Text = HttpContext.Current.Profile["Servco_No"].ToString();
        txtEmp_No.Text = HttpContext.Current.Profile["Emp_No"].ToString();

        Panel pnlRow1 = new Panel();
        Panel pnlRow2 = new Panel();
        Panel pnlContainer = new Panel();

        pnlRow1.CssClass = "row";
        pnlRow2.CssClass = "row";
        pnlContainer.CssClass = "span12";

        pnlRow1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Short Name:  "));
        pnlRow1.Controls.Add(txtShort_name);
        pnlRow1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Servco #:  "));
        pnlRow1.Controls.Add(txtServco_No);
        pnlRow2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Employee #:  "));
        pnlRow2.Controls.Add(txtEmp_No);

        pnlControls.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(pnlRow1);
        pnlControls.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(pnlRow2);
        pnlButton.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(btnSubmit);

        pnlContainer.Controls.Add(pnlControls);
        pnlContainer.Controls.Add(pnlButton);

        Controls.Add(pnlContainer);
        base.CreateChildControls();
    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Profile["Short_name"] = txtShort_name.Text;
        HttpContext.Current.Profile["Servco_no"] = Convert.ToInt32(txtServco_No.Text);
        HttpContext.Current.Profile["Emp_no"] = Convert.ToInt32(txtEmp_No.Text);

        HttpContext.Current.Profile.Save();

        pnlControls.Update();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Further debugging is leading me to believe that this is a problem with my AJAX UpdatePanels. I put breakpoints in the btnSubmit_Click code and in my Page_Load on the page that contains the WebControl, and it got to Page_Load and never to btnSubmit_Click! I thought UpdatePanels were supposed to keep full-page postback from happening?!?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in creating button :

`btnSubmit.Attributes.Add("onclick", "btnSubmit_Click");`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Ehsan, but it didn't work. I added the attribute right after the line that is supposed to be adding my event.

Comment: did you put the "asp:button" tag in the HTML code??? you must add it and match it to the custom code that you made.

Comment: so you don't understand, take a look at these two site : http://www.prowareness.com/blog/custom-asp-net-button-with-image-and-text-and-background-image/ http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_custom_controls.htm